# The integral of polynomial

Tags: calculus

I would like to prove fundamental theorem of algebra and there is a claim that when $p(z)$ is a positive polynomial (since assuming $p(z)$ is a real polynomial (continuous) and there is no zero),
$$\int^{2\pi}_0\frac{1}{p(cos\theta)}d\theta\neq0$$

I have $\int^{2\pi}_0\frac{1}{cos\theta}d\theta\neq0$. I believe the claim makes sense but I'm not sure how to explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function ${1\over p(\cos(\theta))}$ is positive and the integral of a positive function is positive.